# Not getting serial data (USB) from Pico Pi

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

```
from machine import Pin, ADC
import utime

adc = ADC(Pin(26, mode=Pin.IN))
led_onboard = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)


while True:
   val = adc.read_u16()
   u1 = (val*0.0000503547-0.02)*0.992

   print(u1)

   if u1 >= 1.0:
      led_onboard.on()
   else:
      led_onboard.off()
    
   print((val*0.0000503547-0.02)*0.992)
   utime.sleep(0.050)
   led_onboard.off()
   utime.sleep(0.050)
```

I would expect to receive some serial data from the COM-port using Windows 10. The script and hardware itself works, the led blinks if I connect a tripple A battery to the ADC (~1.5V) input.
Interestingly I receive the print data when running the script on the MCU through thonny, so what's going on there?

EDIT/SOLVED
It is actually sending serial data, just checked it with another serial terminal. Don't know what's wrong with HTerm, used it for years